# React causes flickering on hover in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronization, openlayers

I'm using an OpenLayers map in a React component and trying to apply a style to my circle on hover as done in this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html

However, my code is as follows, using refs, and causes flickering:

```js
// OnHover, apply style
    mapRef.current.on('pointermove', function (ev) {
      if (hoveredRef.current !== null) {
        hoveredRef.current.set('hover', 0);
        hoveredRef.current = null;
      }

      mapRef.current.forEachFeatureAtPixel(ev.pixel, feature => {
        feature.set('hover', 1);
        hoveredRef.current = feature;
        return true;
      });
    });
```

Their map works perfectly fine, so I can only assume it has to do with React or my data.

Comment: I found out that in another click event handler, OpenLayers is randomly selecting features from other places on the map (not even close). Why is this happening?

Comment: Hard to say without the react code of the component try to setup a small example on codesandbox . But my guess is, you add multiple times the pointer move event without removing the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

`pointermove` fires at a huge rate and you are adding/removing the `hover` property at each event. You should throttle it and you should also check if you are not hovering over the same feature as the previous event - in this case you should skip updating it. Besides, your implementation breaks if there are overlapping features.

You should probably check rlayers - https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers (disclaimer, I am the author), check the RPopup component - it contains a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for rlayers. I didn't find it before but it'd have been something I'd be really appreciative of. I'm gonna try it.